# Structure of frobenius groups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, frobenius-groups

**Definition**- A groups $G$ is called **Frobenius** if it has a proper nontrivial subgroup $H$ such that $H \cap H^g=1\ \forall\ g\in G-H$.

Do we have a structure or classification theorem for (finite) Frobenius groups that classify all the groups which are Frobenius. I dont think so.

Then how can I get a lot of examples of Frobenius groups?

What commonly seen groups are Frobenius? Like, I know that $D_{2n}$ with $n$ odd is frobenius.

Comment: It is always a good idea to check the Wikipedia page on the subject of one's question and explain if and why what is there, if anything, does not answer one's question, at least in part. This is part of the «Show Your Work» motto.

Comment: I would say this question is too broad. Ask something more specific and you might get a more helpful answer.

Comment: If you are looking for general information besides the wikipedia page, the books Huppert: Endliche Gruppen, Dixon & Mortimer: Permutation groups and D. Robinson: A Course in the Theory of Groups cover them with all the import properties mentioned there. As regarding a classification, in some sense the structure of such groups is quite restrictive and there are many different characterisations. So in some sense they are classified as groups with those properties. But there are many examples among permutation groups, linear groups and so on.